# How to edit the array within a method?

Tags: java, loops, polynomials

So this method is called differentiate, and its purpose is to return a Poly object which consists of an array of doubles, this array should contain the coefficients of the differentiated polynomial for example if provided a poly object that contains an array with `[2.0, 3.0, 2.0]`, the method will return `[4, 3, 0]` because `2x^2 + 3x^1 + 2.0`'s coefficients are those.

```java
public static Poly polyObject;

public static String differentiate(Poly polyObject) {
    double[] array = polyObject.getDoubleArray();
    int counterVariable = array.length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i] * counterVariable;
        counterVariable--;
    }
}
```

Not sure what to do from here in order to change the array's coefficients.

Comment: The example doesn't make sense to me sorry. I didn't get how the coefficients are calculated. But you will need a second for loop to iterate over the array again and make your calculations, and at the end store it to the current index of the array. If you will provide me with an extra example, I will try to help you with an answer.

Comment: So this method should calculate the coefficients for the derivative of the supplied Poly object. It should then create a new Poly object from those coefficients and return it. The "new coefficients" array should ALWAYS be the same length as the original array. Also, you do not need to round coefficients, the coefficients are just the result of calculating the derivate so for example, if 2x^2 was given the derivative is 4x^1 rather than printing the whole thing it would like us to put just the coefficient in the array which is four. Hope that helps

Comment: Because you're looking to represent the answer as 4x + 3, shouldn't the returned array actually be `[0, 4, 3]` (because there is no x^2 component in the answer)?

Comment: Yes, that would make more sense. I believe you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the result by apply [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).  This also shows the resulting coefficients.

- original equation =  `y = 2x^3 + 6x^2 +4x + 3`
- after derivation = `y' = 6x^2 + 12x + 4`
- given `x = 3`, the result is `54 + 36 + 4 = 94`

To solve using `Horner's Method` let `result = 0`

- `result = result * x + 6 = 6  ( exp = 2)`
- `result = result * x + 12 = 30 (exp = 1)`
- `result = result * x + 4 = 94  (exp = 0) - done!`

```
double[] coefs = { 2., 6., 4., 3 };
int exp = coefs.length-1;
double result = 0;
int i = 0;
int x = 3; // the value to be solve
while(i < exp) {
    coefs[i] *= (exp-i);
    result = result * x + coefs[i++];
}


// y = 2x^3 + 6x^2 +4x + 3
// After derivation. coefs = 6, 12, 4
// y' = 6x^2 + 12x + 4    =    54 + 36 + 4
coefs = Arrays.copyOf(coefs,coefs.length-1);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(coefs));
System.out.println("result = " + result);
```

Prints

```
[6.0, 12.0, 4.0]
result = 94.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either return a new array of ints `int[]` like:

```
public static int[] differentiate(Poly polyObject) {

    double[] array = polyObject.getDoubleArray();
    int counterVariable = array.length - 1;
    int[] coeffArray = new int[array.length];    

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        coeffArray[i] = (int) array[i] * counterVariable;
        counterVariable--;
    }

    return coeffArray;
}
```

Or alter the same array but you will have `double` type values and not `int`. This is exactly your code but instead of return type `String` change it to `void`.

```
public static void differentiate(Poly polyObject) {

    double[] array = polyObject.getDoubleArray();
    int counterVariable = array.length - 1;

    for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i] * counterVariable;
        counterVariable--;
    }
}
```